# How to tell about recent past?

Tags: sentence-construction

How to tell someone I had weakness in my body sometime back?

Scenario:

I was playing football and suddenly felt weakness so I stopped playing and went home. When i reached home mother asked me what happened to you?

What should I say?

1) I have had weakness but am now feeling better.

2) I was having weakness but am now feeling better.

3) I had weakness.

any better options?

Comment: You could just use the past: "I felt weak". Also, in English "to have weakness" is not an acceptable phrase. You can use "to feel weak" instead.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you want to describe how you felt with an adjective, rather than saying that you had a noun.

> "She was happy" vs. "She had happiness"
>
> "Charlie felt sick" vs. "Charlie had sickness"

From my experience, it's more natural to do it this way. So, I would say something like this:

> "I felt weak, but now I'm better."

Answer (score 0):

Rather than saying that you *had weakness*, it would be much more idiomatic to say that you *were feeling weak*.

Your best option is probably to use a *simple past* tense for *feel*:

> I **felt** weak, but I'm feeling better now.

With the *past perfect*, you're talking about a more distant past than in the previous sentence:

> I **had felt** weak, but then I felt better.

Not that the entire sentence here is talking about the past and the part about *feeling better* is not happening in the present but has already occurred.

If you use a past continuous, you're stressing a duration and no longer a sudden feeling:

> I had been feeling weak, but I'm better now.